# passbook on the apple watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, passbook

Somewhere in the near future, an application I'm working on is going to its own pass to be stored in the user's passbook.

Since you cannot really test the passbook app from the watch in the simulator, and my watch will be arriving next month, I was hoping someone could shed some light..

I had a few questions about passbook for the apple watch..

1. Is it safe to assume the passes in passbook will automatically be
   synced and added from the phone to the watch?
2. Are there any sort of visual guidelines when it comes to showing
   passes on the apple watch? Does text automatically shrink? are things truncated? Are only certain fields appearing on the watch to conserve space?
3. Is it safe to assume if the user turns their wrist, the screen will
   not shut off if a pass is currently being displayed?

Comment: Question #1 seems like something that's user optional. Question #2 you'll have to do more research. Question #3 I would assume the watch WOULD go blank unless there's setting to delay that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes it automatically syncs.

Thus far I've noticed that the Pass is added to Apple Watch Passbook quite quickly after added in iPhone; although if you reorder the passes on the iPhone the order takes a little longer to sync on the Apple Watch view. (I haven't timed this under different scenarios but I'll test that and get back to you).  Please note, I have >300 passes in Passbook so a 'typical consumer' may not experience the same.

2. Visual Guidelines.

The logo image remains at the top left of the Watch view of the Pass and automatically scales.

The strip or thumbnail image are removed from the Watch view. A background image (on an event ticket type) remains visible but is not scaled.

The header fields moves below the logo image (i.e. it is not to the right of the logo as it appears in the phone).

All other (text) fields appear on the watch view, but they are not side by side. The are presented in a 'list view' - separated by a fine line between each field. I have experienced some situations where the text length runs over one line (e.g. an email address i.e. no spaces between words) and it doesn't look so beautiful as the text does not resize to fit all on one line.

The pass automatically scales width-wise so it fits in the watch view but it is "longer" than the watch screen so you scroll the Pass up and down.

The pass length in the Watch app is dependent on the number of fields used in the Pass.

As you scroll to the QR code and tap on it, all other background colours and the 'close' link disappears and only the barcode is displayed. The square barcodes look significantly better. Of course redemption/scanning still works with the PDF417 barcode but it just doesn't look as nice in the watch view.  It is presented in vertical format in the centre of the watch view, with black to the left and right of the PDF417 barcode.

Please note that there is no 'back view' on the apple watch pass.  i.e. you cannot flip the pass to access the back of the pass as you can on the iPhone.

3. Screen shut off

The screen will not shut off only if the barcode has been selected (as described above).  If you are just viewing the pass and have not selected the barcode the watch screen will shut off after time of no activity or if you turn your wrist.

If the barcode is selected, the barcode remains on the screen irrespective of wrist position and does not shut off over time.

Other - Lockscreen notifications / convenience.

Works the same as iPhone when in proximity to an associated GPS location or beacon or following a push update.

The pass can be accessed by tapping on the notification (i.e. no need to open the Passbook app on the watch) and can also be accessed by a swipe down to notifications. A 'small pass' is displayed in notifications. The 'small pass' is the same width as the watch face, and about half the height (same as other notifications).  It consists of the logo image, inherits the background colour of the Pass, and includes the pass description field (when in proximity) or the updated field (when pushing an update).

Comment: With beacon, does it use the watch Bluetooth or the phone Bluetooth ? Thanks